# How to set position of view while using addView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I'm adding multiple `View`s by code into `Layout`. I need each new `View` to be above previous one(top of the parent layout).

EDIT: To be more accurate I'll describe what the app module should does. User start with clean screen and one button at the bottom of the screen. The button adds a `View` at the top of the screen. Next clicks should add next views above previous ones to make the newest `View` be on the top of a container. The app saves state and on restart user see views in the same order.

Comment: What is the question? And what do you mean by "above previous one"? Do you mean over the top of the previous view? Or do you mean placed above the previous view? Sorry but you really need to be more specific about what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I mean "placed above the previous view". I load some data from database and i want it ordered by the newest record. Its not a problem, becouse i can load it from the end of the list. But later when user dynamically add next view it should appear at the top of the rest. Thats the spirit of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Call** the following method from **Button's onClick Event**.

```
private final int LAYOUT_TOP_INDEX = 0;

private void addViewOnTop(View view){
    if(layout != null && view !=null)
        layout.addView(view, LAYOUT_TOP_INDEX);
}
```

where **'layout'** is your Layout (e.g., LinearLayout) to which the View is to be added.

Answer (score 1):

Would really need more information from you to give a more accurate answer, but if you're saying what i think you are then you can just add these views to a LinearLayout with orientation set to vertical.

And assuming you're iterating through a list to dynamically add views, instead of incrementing from 0, increment down from the size of the list.

```
for(int i = size; i >= 0; i--){
   linearLayout.add(new TextView(Context));
}
```

Comment: It's okay, but I'havnt give you enough details, so your answer is a bit missed.

Answer (score 1):

`View` positions inside `ViewGroup`s are defined by the `LayoutParams`

How does this happen? Views pass their LayoutParams to their parent ViewGroups

```
    //100% programatic approach with simple LayoutParams
                LinearLayout myLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

    //if the **parent** of the new linear layout is a FrameLayout 
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

                //or if you have the XML file you don't have to worry about this
                //myLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_simple_linear_layout);


                //you could have a LinkedList<TextView>
                LinkedList<TextView> textViewList = new LinkedList<>();


                //assuming the order is the correct order to be displayed
                Iterator<TextView> descendingIterator = textViewList.descendingIterator();

                while(descendingIterator.hasNext())
                {
                    //just add each TextView programatically to the ViewGroup
                    TextView tView = descendingIterator.next();
                    myLinearLayout.addView(tView);
                }
```

Just like we defined `LayoutParams` for the `LinearLayout` we could also define LayoutParams for the `TextView`

IMPORTANT: when setting LayoutParams you need to be sure they **fit** the VIEWGROUP, that is the **parent** of the View being added

```
private TextView textViewFactory(String myText) {


            TextView tView = new TextView(getBaseContext());

            //controling the position relatively to the PARENT
            //because you are adding the textview to a LINEAR LAYOUT
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsExample =
                    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);

            tView.setLayoutParams(paramsExample);


            //configuring the insides of the textview
            //you can also do all kinds of stuff programatically
            tView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

            tView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            tView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);// (null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
            tView.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
            tView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
            tView.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(R.style.AppTheme));
            tView.setId(R.id.aux_info);

            tView.setText(myText);
            //.........all kinds of stuff really

            return tView;
    }
```

Comment: @Gniewomir I only saw the edit after completing the answer, do you want the complete code for the button as well?

Comment: That's should be enough, I'm going to test your answer today. Thank you for beautiful answer.

Comment: @Gniewomir alright then ;) if you run into any problem with the code let me know  or mark the answer as accepted please =)

Comment: This solution is good and well explained, but the selected answer is more simple and accurate.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean adding a view programmatically so that the new one is added above the previous one, instead of below it, then I suggest this:

- Maintain an ArrayList with the items you want to turn into views
- Put them into a ListView
- When you want to add a new view that must appear at the top of the list, insert it as the first element of your ArrayList and recreate the ListView from it.

Comment: That would work, but I wanted to avoid using ListView. Selected answer worked best in my case.